# collecting tweets using twitter API in R language

Tags: r, twitter, package, rstudio

i am trying to collect tweets using TwitteR package in an R language
i am using Rstudio as an environment to build my code
i was able to collect tweets in English. 
but, when i specify the language to Arabic it collect tweets that are not related to search string that i have provided to the function searchTwitter()
here is the code i am using to collect tweets

```
rdmTweets <- searchTwitter("حب#", n=5, lang= "ar")
```

do you have any suggestions to solve this problem?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: can you try with a non-ascii but latin character? for example, Zürich